# ZF2 - Record not existing

Tags: database, zend-framework2, record, validation

I try to use the zf2 db validator to check if a record does not exist.

I set the follow code in my controller:

```
$validator = new NoRecordExists(
                array(
                    'table'   => 'topics',
                    'field'   => 'topic',
                )
            );
```

after this configuration I try to validate but I got 'an error occurred', can't find any other error output who can tell me more about this error.

```
var_dump($validator->isValid('test'));
```

If someone can give me some tips, would be great :)

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the DB Adapter?

You can pass it in the contructor or called setAdapter();

```
validator->setAdapter(
    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
);
```

You could set this up in your service config to automatically inject the adapter for you.

Comment: Geat, that's what I needed exactly :). Works! merci